# Is there a word for the side of a shoe that touches the ground but is perpendicular?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a word for the band going around a shoe right above where it touches the ground? Not the sole, which is parallel to the ground, but the part on the side that is perpendicular to the ground?

For example, when describing the shoe below, you might say that its ____ is black:

[image]

Comment: i think it might be "trim"?

Comment: No, that is called the welt or rand. The side of  a shoe doesn't have a name per se. The layers making up the sole do. OR the outer and midsole are black.

Comment: @Lambie In a traditional shoe, the side is called *the upper*. Or at least it used to ne. But in a modern shoe of this kind I suppose all terminology is up for grabs.

Comment: No, the upper is the entire bit above the sole, which includes the sides of course. Shoe terminology can get very complicated and I am too lazy to go and get a glossary. You will see welt and rand in any good glossary.

Comment: 'band' would do - the wikipedia plimsoll and shoemaking articles use that for a vertical join rather than a welt which sort of folds over, but I don't have better references.

Comment: Yes, for marketing purposes band would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the image below, it appears that the part in question is referred to as the ***[midsole](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/midsole):***

> - a layer (as of leather or rubber) between the insole and the outsole of a shoe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The welt and outsole: this is a technical answer.

http://www.bellsshoes.co.uk/shoe-glossary-i168
Welt - A piece of leather which is sewn between the outsole and the insole, this can sometimes be designed to stick-out to create more detailing

Your picture shoes a welt + outsole in black.